# Check if an $n$-dimensional segment intersects with an $n$-dimensional sphere

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Everything is in a $\mathbb{R}^n$ space for a finite $n$.

Given a line segment defined by two $n$-dimensional points $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ (the segment will be called $ab$) and a robot walking in a straight line between them. I want to check if it passed near a point $\vec{p}$ during its walk. "Passing near" means that at any point it was a distance $r$ or less away from $\vec{p}$. To check this, I can calculate the segment $ab$ intersects an $n$-dimensional sphere with radius $r$ and its center at $\vec{p}$.

At first, I thought about calculating the distance between $\vec{p}$ and the line continuing $ab$ and check if the closest point is inside the segment. But, this misses the cases where the point is close enough to $ab$ but the closest point to $p$ is outside the segment $ab$ (see picture), how can I check if an $n$-sphere intersects a section in vector calculation?

Will adding a check of the distance of the edges ($\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$) from $\vec{p}$ enough, or are there other cases this misses?

To get the distance of $\vec{p}$ from $ab$:

$$
n = \vec{b}-\vec{a}
$$
$$
t = \left(\vec{a}-\vec{p}\right)\cdot\vec{n}
$$
$$
dist = \left\Vert\left(\vec{a}-\vec{p}\right)-t\cdot\vec{n}\right\Vert
$$

And the condition of $0{\leq}t\leq\left\Vert{n}\right\Vert$ or $\left\Vert\vec{a}-\vec{p}\right\Vert{\leq}r$ or $\left\Vert\vec{b}-\vec{p}\right\Vert{\leq}r$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a standard exercise in linear algebra to compute the coordinates of the point on the line $\overline{ab}$ (not the segment!) closest to $p$. If this outside the circle then you are done. If it is inside the circle then check whether it is on the line segment. If yes, then you are done. If no, check whether $a$ or $b$ are inside the circle. If yes, you are done. If no, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

i) If $A$ or $B$ is internal to the ball: the segment intersects intersect the ball

ii) elif (both points are external),
   put ${\bf u}$ to be the unitary vector parallel to $\vec {AB}$;
if $0 \le \lambda =\vec{AP} \cdot {\bf u} \le |AB|$  then P projects into a point $H$ internal to the segment ($\lambda = |AH|$)
and if $|\vec{HP} = \vec{AP} - \lambda {\bf u}| \le r$ , the point $H$ and thus a part of the segment is internal to the ball.